# How to match array of string in select query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am work in php and this is my array

Array ( [0] => Sharp [1] => New [2] => Stress [3] => Bending forward [4] => Headache )

And I Want to retrieve the record which match the array value in tag column

```
select * 
from table_name 
where tag In(Sharp, New,Stress,Bending forward,Headache);
```

But above query give the error in php side as like

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Demo\abc.php on line 14

And mysql side is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'forward,Headache) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Thank you in advance

Comment: Missing quotes for string

Comment: but i want match all value which store in array

Comment: Check the given below answers u will get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes for your string value.

This:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag IN (Sharp,New,Stress,Bending forward,Headache)
```

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag IN ('Sharp','New', 'Stress','Bending forward','Headache')
```

If you have an array than you can use `implode()`

```
$string = implode('","',$yourArray);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag IN ("'.$string.'")';
```

One more point, as per your code error you are using `mysql_*` extension which is deprecated and closed in PHP 7. You can use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.